# Let X be a random variable with the p.d.f.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ be a random variable with the p.d.f.
>
> $f(x) = \begin{cases}1/2 + x/4  &\mbox{if}& -2\leq  x <0  
>        \\1/2 - x/4 &\mbox{if}& ~~~0\leq  x <2  
>        \\ 0 &&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$
>
> (i) Calculate $\mathsf P(|X| < 1 )$.
>
> (ii) Calculate $F(x) = \mathsf P(X \leqslant x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
P(|X|<1)=\int_{-1}^1f(x) \ dx.
$$
and 
$$
P(X\leq x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(x)\ dx.
$$
Now you do the rest.

Comment: So for part (i) I would just do the integral of 1/2+x/4 from -1 to 1, and for part (ii) I would do the intgeral of 1/2-x/4 from −∞ to x?

Comment: @KGT be careful. For part i, you have to break up the integral from -1 to 1 into the sum of two integrals: from -1 to 0 and from 0 to 1, since f(x) has different expressions on each of these intervals.

Comment: No, @KGT.  $f(X)$ is a piecewise function.  Look at where the pieces lie with respect to the integration bounds.

Comment: @KGT similarly for part ii, you have to deal with cases. One case if x<0 and one case if x > 0.

Comment: ok thanks for all the help.